# asp.net web.config timeouts

Tags: asp.net, session, web-config, timeout

Here is a snippet from my web.config file:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="1440"></sessionState>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="1440" 
             cookieless="UseCookies" 
             />
  </authentication>
```

I am getting sessions expiring much sooner than 1 day (within an hour or so).  Are there any other IIS or ASP.NET settings that could be affecting this? (the app is not setting any timeouts from code).

Comment: @Neil Knight - no - will these cause a session timeout?

Comment: Is it the 'Shutdown worker processes after being idle for' setting? (currently 20 mins)

Comment: @Neil - if you enter this as the answer I can give you the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the `application pool`s recycle time.  This is probably the cause as I think that it defaults to something like 20 minutes.